# git merge some commits from develop branch into existing release branch?

Tags: git, merge, smartgit

I have a `develop` branch which our team works on and we created a `release` branch off of it about a month ago. Now some of the commits done in `develop` need to be merged into the `release` branch.

I switched to my `release` branch and then did a `cherry pick` of commits I wanted. This worked but now when I look at the log, I can't tell which `develop` commits that I didn't move over. It's very confusing. How can I get a report of what files have been modified in `develop` that aren't in the `release` branch?

FYI, I'm using smartgit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `git diff develop..release` to get the diffs between your two branches.

You could also use `gitk develop release` to open a GUI which would let you get the same kind of diff.

Answer (score 0):

To see what files are different between develop and release use

```
git diff --name-only release..develop --
```